# Проблема получения сообщения от сервера

Tags: c#, tcpclient

Нужно получить сообщение от сервера, отправить ему расшифрованное сообщение и получить ответ о проделанной работе (Good Jon, Too slow или Wrong). Я получаю сообщение, расшифровываю и отправляю обратно, (UPD) но возвращает туже самую строку что при первом обращении. Расстояние между сервером и мной примерно 3000 км.

```
// Определение сервера

IPAddress ipAddr = IPAddress.Parse("185.111.219.128");
IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, 8888);
TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient();

tcpClient.Connect(endPoint);
// Создание базового потока
NetworkStream tcpStream = tcpClient.GetStream();

byte[] bytes = new byte[256];
int bytesRead = tcpStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

// Строка, содержащая ответ от сервера
string returnData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
char[] dMessage = new char[returnData.Length];
Console.WriteLine(returnData);

//Расшифровка текста

string answer = intToString(int_dMessage);

byte[] answerBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(answer);
tcpStream.Write(answerBytes, 0, answerBytes.Length);

Thread.Sleep(100);
bytesRead = tcpStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

// Строка, содержащая ответ от сервера
returnData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
Console.WriteLine(returnData);
```

---

Update

Сервер не мой, логи тоже посмотреть не могу. Ошибок не выдает. Возврашает туже саму строку что и при первом обращении, т.е. зашифрованную строку.

Сервер отправляет зашифрованную строку, и ждет получение расшифрованной строки. После получения строки отправлет сообщение клиенту (Good job, Wrong, Too slow). С помощью команды netcat ответ удавалось получить, так что сервер работает корректно. Проблема где то в коде, и я не могу понять где.

Comment: Сервер не мой, логи тоже посмотреть не могу. Ошибок не выдает. UPD: Возврашает туже саму строку что и при первом обращении, т.е. зашифрованную строку.

Comment: Сервер отправляет зашифрованную строку, и ждет получение расшифрованной строки. После получения строки отправлет сообщение клиенту (Good job, Wrong, Too slow). С помощью команды netcat ответ удавалось получить, так что сервер работает корректно. Проблема где то в коде, и я не могу понять где.

Comment: А вы точно отправляете ответ в нужном формате? И правильно вы расшифровываете сообщение?

Comment: Расшифровываю правильно. Про формат, тут вы почти угадали. Решение найдено: в конце отправляемого сообщения нужен был символ переноса корретки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно добавить символ переноса корректки в конец расшифрованного сообщения, плюс добавить ожидание после отправки.